# How to secure a Web API from the native client, when the user context is not available?

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, oauth, native, azure-active-directory

We have a multi-tenanted native Cordova mobile application,  tenants can choose from two types of authentication

```
1. Forms authentication
2. Azure active directory (OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow)
```

The mobile app calls  the REST APIs built using Web API 2.2., the Api's look either for custom token or Bearer token based on the tenant .

When the user first time logs into the mobile app, he will be shown a textbox to enter the tenant name and from the backed we call  GetTenantDetails API to check the authentication mechanism configured for the tenant

```
1. If it is a forms authentication we show custom user name and password form 
2. If it is a Azure active directory type, we redirect the user to Azure login age
```

we have to call this backend API  so that we take a decision to show appropriate login page

**How to secure GetTenantDetails API to call only from authorized mobile client when there is no user context available ?**

I have looked at OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow, which works perfectly for the MVC web app, but as the native application cannot keep the secret we can't use it in mobile scenario.

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Are you saying you want an unauthenticated client and unauthenticated user to call `GetTenantDetails`? Why?

Comment: Hi Phlilippe, I have added more details to the question to answer your query.

Comment: What information in GetTenantDetails are you using to decide which auth method to use?

Comment: tenant data has identity provider inforation whether custom or aad

Comment: Which property from the `GetTenantDetails`, specifically, are you using here?